# How to Handle the RAISERROR in SQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, raiseerror

I want to handle the below Error into a variable, so that I can store it in a table

```
RAISERROR ('Error occurred "%s" after 10 passes.', 1, 1, @Requesterr)
```

I need to get whole error from above command and store it in table.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Are you sure you use `MySQL` and not `Microsoft SQL Server`?

Comment: Use the correct database.  `raiseerror` is in SQL Server.  MySQL uses `signal`.

Comment: That should be sql server... Mysql is invalid tag..!!! below answer helps an extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`FORMATMESSAGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186788.aspx) to format error message:

```
DECLARE @error_msg VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Requesterr VARCHAR(100) = 'incorrect path';

SET @error_msg = FORMATMESSAGE('Error occurred "%s" after 10 passes.', @Requesterr);

RAISERROR (@error_msg, 1, 1);

-- INSERT INTO error_log(message)
-- VALUE (@error_msg);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/401032)**</kbd>